# Using map with ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs

I am using reactjs to hit a php array.  I'm doing this through a fetch request like so:

```
componentDidMount() {
  fetch("http://localhost:8001/testing", {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Methods':"GET, POST, PUT, DELETE,OPTIONS",
      'Content-Type': '"application/json'
    }
  }).then(response => {
    response.json()
    .then(data => {
      console.log(data);
      let legoParts = data.map((legoPart) => {

        return (
          <div key={legoPart.id}>
            {legoPart.name}
          </div>
        );

      });

      this.setState({legoParts: legoParts})
    });
  }).catch(function(err) {
    console.log("i failed");
  });
}
```

However I am having problems displaying the contents of the array/objects.  At the first console.log (console.log(data)) the results are as follows:

```
 (2) [{…}, {…}]
  0:{id: 1, piece: "tree", type: "garden"}
  1: {id:2 piece:"hat" type: "clothes"}
 __proto__:Object
 length:2
 __proto__:Array(0)
```

But I can't figure out how to actually just display the values for each object.  Grateful for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The objects in your array of objects contain the `piece` and `type` keys, and not the `name` key.

```
return (
  <div key={legoPart.id}>
    <div>{legoPart.piece}</div>
    <div>{legoPart.type}</div>
  </div>
);
```

Then, to "just display" these divs, return `this.state.legoParts` in your component's `render` method.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that your array element doesn't contain "name" key, that's why you see empty divs. You will receive result if you replace your dive with for example:

```
<div key={legoPart.id}>
  {legoPart.type + " " + legoPart.piece}
</div>
```